# Max value for cache control header in HTTP

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, cache-control

I'm using Amazon S3 to serve static assets for my website. I want to have browsers cache these assets for as long as possible. What meta-data headers should I include with my assets

```
Cache-Control: max-age=???
```

Comment: the possible max-age value is dependent on browser/version and any proxy in the way... AFAIK there is not real standard/spec so any value would be a guess...

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Generally one year is advised as a standard max value. See [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> To mark a response as "never expires," an origin server sends an
>   Expires date approximately one year from the time the response is
>   sent. HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more than one
>   year in the future.

Although that applies to the older `expires` standard, it makes sense to apply to `cache-control` too in the absence of any explicit standards guidance. It's as long as you should generally need anyway and picking any arbitrarily longer value could break some user-agents. So:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

Comment: `Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, immutable` can be used to make use of the new `immutable` directive where supported (currently quite limited). See: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#immutable), [blog post](https://ashton.codes/set-cache-control-max-age-1-year/)

Answer (score 24):

Consider not storing it for "as long as possible," and instead settling for as long as reasonable.  For instance, it's unlikely you'd need to cache it for longer than say 10 years...am I right?

The RFC discusses max-age here:  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3

Eric Lawrence says that prior to IE9, Internet Explorer would treat as stale any resource with a Cache-Control: max-age value over 2147483648 (2^31) seconds, approximately 68 years (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx).

Other user agents will of course vary, so...try and choose a number that is unlikely (rather than likely!) to cause an overflow.  Max-age greater than 31536000 (one year) makes little sense, and informally this is considered a reasonable maximum value.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the specific headers to send. I have a mechanism built into my website to change the url of the file to point to a different filename if i need to make a change and have visitors see it. I just need an example of the specific headers to send to get browsers to cache these assets indefinitely.

Comment: Cache-Control: max-age=31536000 will cache it for 1 year, which is the max-recommended.

Comment: @Geoffrey: I think you're confused about what Casey is building. He's simply saying that he'll change the URL he references in his markup when the version changes. This is a best practice used by most top sites.

Comment: @Geoffrey Are you sure it's "over 2147483648"? I'd thought it was "over 2147483647"?

Answer (score 5):

The people who created the recommendation of maximum 1 year caching did not think it through properly.

First of all, if a visitor is being served an outdated cached file, then why would it provide any benefit to have it suddenly load a fresh version after 1 year? If a file has 1 year TTL, from a functional perspective, it obviously means that the file is not intended to be changed at all.

**So why would one need more than 1 year?**

**1) Why not?** It doesn't server any purpose to tell the visitors browser "hey, this file is 1 year old, it might be an idea to check if it has been updated".

**2) CDN services.** Most content delivery networks use the cache header to decide how long to serve a file efficiently from the edge server. If you have 1 year cache control for the files, it will at some point start re-requesting non-changed files from the origin server, and edge-cache will need to be entirely re-populated, causing slower loads for client, and unnecessary calls to the origin.

What is the point of having max 1 year? What browsers will choke on an amount set higher than 31536000?

Comment: 1 year is an eternity in internet age. Plus if you take caching seriously you would handle (in addition to cache-control) the last-modified and/or etag mechanism. So even those re-requests a year later won't harm the bandwidth (304 not modified)

Comment: 1 year is not an eternity when your images are NEVER changed (like most images on the internet), and when you don't want a CDN to refresh files from the origin (which would be pointless). As for last-modified/etag, of course that initiates a request and dialog between client and server, just to find out what we already know "yup, its still ok to serve the cached file". Your argument is basically "1 year is an eternity on the internet", which doesn't serve anything productive. I have set 10 years expire on images, which simply serves a better end result.

Comment: Oh and  there is also default browser cache size. Would any cached asset survive a year in a browser cache ? I don't know.

Comment: Extremely unlikely. Something which further proves the pointlessness of setting "1 year" when it serves no other purpose than attempting to cache an item "forever" or "as long as possible" ...

Comment: It isn't about the browser caching it. It is about intermediate proxies caching it such as Akamai and Varnish and Google's mobile proxy etc.

Comment: I agree with @suncat100 and Eijah here. It makes sense to store long-lived assets in your CDN as long as the data isn't state. There are many business use cases where this is true for more than a year for many assets.

Comment: There are valid reasons, For instance I have web kiosks that when they boot up, the service worker caches a response of their default URL. This allows them to boot up if there is no Internet. The terminals are restarted only after christmas shutdown, so they only see the page one a year if all goes well. Just cause some people can't see past their own use case, doesnt mean there are other valid cases.

Comment: @run_the_race and what difference does that make in your case if an asset is cached for 1 year vs 10 years? Not a logical response.

Comment: @suncat100 I think you are assuming people will disagree with you, actually the point of my post was agreeing that sometimes you need longer than a year cache headers.

Comment: @run_the_race ok sorry, old post I lost track :D