# Cache busting index.html in a .Net Core Angular 5 website

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular-cli, browser-cache

I am creating a website using .Net core and angular 5. I created the project using the latest .Net core angular template (using `dotnet new angular` with .Net core 2.1 installed).

This project uses the angular cli to build/package and applies a hash onto the bundled js and css files:

[image]

However after publishing my site to an azure app service I found that when I browsed to the site I would see the old version until I manually refreshed with F5 (Ctrl-F5 wasn't necessary). This seems to be because although the js/css files wont be cached, the index.html page which contains the references to these files will be served from the cache.

When I press F5 to reload the website the index.html (`home` below) is requested from the site (304 in this case as it hasn't changed, if it has it will get the latest):

[image]

However when I initially load the page (via a bookmark or typing in the address etc) the page is directly served from cache:

[image]

Is this expected behaviour? Why is it different loading the page for the first time vs pressing F5? And can I/should I prevent this caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a neat or perfect solution but this seems to have worked and might get people on the right track:

In Configure() in Startup.cs I added this

```
app.Use(async (c, next) =>
{
    if (c.Request.Path == "/")
    {
        c.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-store,no-cache");
        c.Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    }
    await next();
});
```

Since adding this I haven't been able to reproduce my issue.

Comment: Will this cache every single file or just index.html file ? I didn't really get who the c.Request.Path == "/" check match the index.html file

Comment: @ZhenyiZhang This will disable caching by adding the no-cache headers. The request path check ensures this is only applied when the request path is empty (i.e it will apply when the request is www.example.com, but not www.example.com/api/foo).

Comment: @QTom any request can return the index.html if its the client's first time navigating to that page. IE: if I open my browser and go to www.example.com/api/foo immediately, then it will return the index.html but will not be cached because request path was not empty.

Answer (score 19):

Here's what I ended up with after combining a bunch of answers. My goal was to never cache index.html. While I was in there, and since Angular nicely cache-busts the `js` and `css` files, I had it cache all other assets for a year.

Just make sure you're using a cache-busting mechanism for assets, like images, that you're managing outside of Angular.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  // ...
  app.UseStaticFiles();

  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    // no caching
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
      OnPrepareResponse = context =>
      {
        context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000");
        context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "31536000");
      }
    });
  }

  // ...

  app.UseSpa(spa =>
  {
    spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
    {
      OnPrepareResponse = context =>
      {
        // never cache index.html
        if (context.File.Name == "index.html")
        {
          context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
          context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "-1");
        }
      }
    };
  });
}
```

Other StackOverflow Answers: [Disable Caching in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45329316/856692) | 
[Cache for a year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25201898/856692)

Comment: The source you are referring to uses a modification of `app.UseStaticFiles()`, you are using a modification of `app.UseSpaStaticFiles` and indicate that without any parameters no caching is being done. Later within `UseSpa(spa =>` you continue with another approach to disable caching for html files. A bit confusing as to what would work and what not. When debugging both solutions, index.html does not come up and therefor does not add any headers to this file. I see that within `UseSpaStaticFiles`, all image, svg and json files are passing by and I can correctly control these files..

Comment: ..but the breakpoint within `DefaultPageStaticFileOptions` never gets hit. Atleast within the development environment.

Comment: After publishing it to a test environment, I notice that there is a difference between dev and 'production'. I did not use the `if-else` for `env.IsDevelopment()` and I did in both `OnPrepareResponse` an equal `if-else` condition for index.html. One of the options configured correctly to apply `no cache, no-store`.

Comment: Thanks for this. A minor correction - the only other directive that applies when using `no-store` is `max-age`; `no-cache` is a conflicting directive that has no effect. MDN recommends using `no-store, max-age=0` if you want to clear any existing cached responses, or just `no-store` if you only want to prevent caching going forward. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#preventing_caching