# Caching ActiveStorage URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a partial where I store website icons: touch icon, favorites icon, Android/Apple icons, like 25 of them.

These icons change rarely close to never. I keep them all in S3 with CloudFront on top. I don't want to move them to /public/icons as I'd have to go around ActiveStorage everytime I run into something like this.

This partial takes like 200ms to render.

How do I cache this for like, forever, as the URLs to the icons expire after 5 minutes or so? Is there still no way to get a permanent URL to the asset from Rails?

Comment: use the s3 metata cache-control: max-age higher for these and for other use max-age 5 minutes.

Comment: What is the maximum cache duration?

Comment: 31536000 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071763/max-value-for-cache-control-header-in-http

Comment: @JamesDean You can only do that to already uploaded file, but not set it as default